# How to load content on click in yii2 framework?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I'm working on yii2 project and we need to load blocks with ajax on click.
I wrote ajax part that works correctly but im stuck with javascript. My mentor says I should use .append but I cant find way to link it somehow with controller action.

php:

```
 public function actionGetProjects() {

        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

                $projects = Project::find()->orderBy('created_at DESC')->limit(15)->offset($post['page']*15)->all();

                if (count($projects)>0) {
                    $this->return['code'] = 200;
                    $this->return['html'] = $this->renderPartial('_projects', [
                            'projects' => $projects
                    ]);
                } else {

                    $this->return['code'] = 404;
                }
        return json_encode($this->return);
    }
```

UPD:

HTML

```
<div class="projects">
    <div class="pageHeader">My Projects</div>
    <?php foreach ($projects as $project) {?>
    <a href="project/<?=$project->id?>" class="project-block">


                <img src="<?=$project->projectImages[0] ? '/img/products/'.$project->projectImages[0]->image:''?>">

                <div class="project-title"><?=$project->name?></div>
                <div class="project-address"><?=$project->address?></div>
                <div class="project-readmore">Read more</div>


    </a>
  <?php  } ?>
    <a class="projects-load-btn" href="#">Еще</a>

</div>
```

New JS:

```
$(".projects-load-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id") || 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/get-projects',
        data: { id: id },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.code == 200){
                $('.projects').addClass('test');
                $('.projects').html('');
                $('.projects').append(data);
            }
        },
        errors: function (errors) {
            console.log(errors);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The code you show is the php code and the question is about the javascript? What do you have tried in js so far?

Comment: Yeah, sorry cant get along with formatting here.
$(document).on('click','.projects-load-btn',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id') || 0;
    $(".projects").append("/controllers/AjaxController.php",{action:"getProjects", id:id});
});

Comment: I dont see any ajax call in your code and we have no idea what your html structure looks like and what is `.projects`, add the view that you are using

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `urlManager` component configured with `enablePrettyUrl` set to true in your config file?

If so, yii2 uses the following default routing template: `<controller>/<action>`

In you case this would result in `/ajax/get-projects` url.

The complete JavaScript code would look something like this:

```
$(".projects-load-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/get-projects",
        data: { id: id }
    }).done(function (data) {
        $(".projects").append(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your response. I already found out right way to write url of action. Also I've come up with such js script(updated the post). Could you explain for what purposes you use    `var id = $(this).data("id") || 0;`? Also my js code doesnt work and responses with these errors:
`jquery-1.12.4.js:10254 POST http://index.loc/ajax/get-projects 500 (Internal Server Error)

send @ jquery-1.12.4.js:10254

ajax @ jquery-1.12.4.js:9738

(anonymous) @ main.min.js:1
dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.js:5226
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.js:4878`
Could you please look at it?

Comment: You need to look inside of you `runtime/logs/app.log`.
It's not JS problem.

Regarding the code `var id = $(this).data("id") || 0;` - I copied it from your very first post. Usually I don't use `|| 0` at all.
I've updated my code, to the version I use in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you should not send the action as a variable through POST.
It depends on how routing was set in your Yii2 app, thus I'm only guessing:

An ajax call:

```
$.post("Ajax/getProjects", {id:id}, function(data) { ... });
```

Appending something in DOM:

```
$(".projects").append(jsonResponse.html);
```

Guessing this is school work, thus not giving the whole solution...

Comment: Thank you very much. Its not school project, its more like me and my friends trying to set up our merchandise website and my uncle is programmer so when I have trouble I call to him, this time he said I have to do smth with append and if I wont success then head to stackoverflow. I must admit JS isnt my strong side, we had joomla site before so I got into php mostly.  I ll try to do it with help you provided, thank you!

Comment: Well, the `append()` goes in the function that triggers on the success/done event from the ajax request. And the Html would be in `data.html`

Comment: You can refer to the jQuery website. They have great documentation.
And if you search SO, you might find similar questions on here... You are not the only one that is/was a beginner in Javascript :) Good luck...